# Can you create a "Comments" section in a SharePoint wiki?

Tags: sharepoint, comments, wiki

I'm trying to create a Comments section in my wiki.  There's one solution on the Web involving the creation of a "column," but that seemed to just create a second text block under the main article block.  This is impractical, because subsequent edits don't create new comments - they seem to just edit the existing comment.  There are a few others asking this question out there.  Has anyone done anything like this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first recommendation would be to try and get a different wiki solution.  I tried to get the Sharepoint wiki adopted and it failed in a much bigger way then expected.  Then I convinced my company that it was the wiki that was the problem.  After switching wiki's we experienced a much greater adoption.

That said, the way that I did comments on the Sharepoint wiki was to make a separate page for every page that I wanted comments on.  Then at the top of the page I would have a standard table.

```
The Page   |  Comments
```

This table would link you to a talk like page on wikipedia.  This solved the issue to a certain extent for me.

Check out [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/), it's my favorite wiki software out there right now.

Comment: Thanks!  I was trying hard not to spend any money, but we have been looking at Confluence too.  Might have to bite the bullet.  I'll give your solution a shot first, though!

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following line to the page layout of the enterprise wiki worked for me

```
<SharePointPortalControls:SocialCommentWebPart id="noteboard" ChromeType="None" runat="server" />
```